# CSS - How to code fluid DIV columns, that reacts to display changes with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, web

I'm straggling with a simple layout issue:

Basically my goal is to create a toggled side menu. When the side menu is visible the main layout is 80% width, and when it is not visible the main layout would be 100% width, like so:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap 3 and would like to use their CSS markup, so I can add rows and columns to the main div (Lt-orange in the illustration).

Any help would be appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

Here is my progress so far:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="sidebar" style="border:solid 1px;width:20%;float:left">SIDEBAR</div>
<div style="border:solid 1px;width:100%">
    <div style="border:solid 1px red">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">Some Content</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">Some content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display = document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display == 'none' ? 'block':'none'">TOGGLE</button>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3DGB/2/)

Comment: You should know by know: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Noted ... sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't use 20% because bootstrap grid size works with 12s. Which means 100%=12/12 so 1/12 is 8,33% is the smallest unit. What is closest to you is for the sidebar to be 3/12=25%. Giving you code for this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    sidebar content
  </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
    main content here
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      your 100% main content here
    </div>
  </div
</div>
```

I assume the bottom photo shows how it will look on a mobile device..?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no the side bar is toggled on desktop. on your example when the first column display is none, the second one is still col-sm-9

Comment: ...if you don't need anything different than 25% and 75% for screens larger than 'small' ones you don't have to add -md-X or -lg-X.

Comment: Right, but I'm still left with the basic issue: how to make the second column stretch to 100% once the first column is display:none

Comment: that's what col-xs-12 on the sidebar element does. This is basic stuff, replace your code with mine and you'll see how it works

Comment: Thanks again, correct me is I'm wrong but col-xs-12 will response to changes on screen size, not a manipulation to the first column style. Maybe I should be more clear.

Comment: well, what you are asking for has nothing to do with bootstrap code. Depending on how would you toggle you would also add custom function to change stuff. You SHOULD be more clear and also I suppose it's not right to use my code as your own in the edit screen, at least not without giving any credit for it.

Comment: Noted, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar kind of solution, below is the snippet of code that works for me
below is the file (test.php)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Toggle Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH TO/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH/demo.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-sm-3 side20" > This is side content</div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 main80">This is the main content.</div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default" role="button">Toggle</button>
  <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-sm-3 side20" >n</div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 main80" >This is the main content</div>

  </div>

<footer class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 copyright">
    &copy Toggle Demo - <?php echo date('Y');?>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 design">
    <small>Designed by Learner</small>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="PATH TO/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="PATH TO/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH TO/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The sample css is (demo.css)

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    background: #0081c2;
}
.side20{
    background: #3e8f3e;
}
.col-sm-3{
    display: block;
    background: #3e8f3e;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
}
.main80{
    background: #8D0D19;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
}
.col-sm-12{
    background: #8D0D19;
}
footer{
min-height: 50px;
background: #010102;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.copyright{
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
.design{
text-align: right;
line-height: 50px;
    color: #FFF4B9;
}
```

And the toggle function is achieved by the below jQuery script (custom.js)

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
    $(".col-sm-3").toggle();
    $(".main80").toggleClass("col-sm-12");
    $(".main80").toggleClass("col-sm-9");
});
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Found a CSS only solution , basically I'm using table display:

**HTML + CSS**:

```
<div class="container">
<div style="display:table;width:100%;border:solid 1px red;height:100px">
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div id="side" style="display:table-cell;background:#CCC;width:30%">SIDE</div>
        <div style="display:table-cell">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">6 col</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">6 col</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toggle()">TOGGLE</button>
```

[here is a JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7p6t/), that toggles the display of the cell